# Run code on application startup Phoenix Framework (Elixir)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Were would you put code which you want to run only when your application/api starts in vanilla Phoenix application? Let's say I want to make sure some mnesia tables are created or configure my logger backend. The other thing is runtime configuration. They mention it in documentation but it's not clear to me where one would define/change runtime configuration.

`Endpoint.ex` seems like a place where initial configuration is done but by looking at docs I can't find any callback that would allow me to run code only once at startup.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Put it in the application callback module.  It is usually the name of your application: `lib/my_app/my_app.ex` in the `start/2` function.  The 2nd line of the module should have `use Application`.

Comment: Now when you said it is so obvious ... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I named my project "test", so before I read this answer, I thought that file is a unittest module!!